# How to insert pivot table in case of many to many relation? (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot-table, laravel-5.3

My form to add data is like this :

[image]

When klik save, It will call controller

My controller is like this :

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $param = $request->only('account_name','account_number','bank_id','branch');
    $result = $this->user_service->addUserBank($param);

    if($result)
        $status='success';
    else
        $status = 'failed';
    return redirect('member/profile/setting/account')->with('status',$status);
}
```

My service is like this :

```
public function addUserBank($param)
{
    $instance = User::where('id', '=', auth()->user()->id)->first();
    $param['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
    $param['status'] = 0;
    $instance->banks()->attach([
                'status' => $param['status'], 
                'account_name' => $param['account_name'],
                'account_number' => $param['account_number'],
                'branch' => $param['branch']
            ]);
    return $result;
}
```

My model user is like this :

```
<?php
namespace App;
use App\Models\MasterData;
use Collective\Html\Eloquent\FormAccessible;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, FormAccessible;
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password', 'api_token','birth_date','mobile_number','gender','full_name'
    ];
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
    public function banks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MasterData::class, 'users_banks', 'user_id', 'bank_id')  ->withPivot('status','account_name','account_number','branch')->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

So I have 3 table : users table, users_banks table (pivot table), and master_datas table

List of the names of the banks located in the master_datas table with type bank

Users table have field id, name, email, password etc => See model user

Master_datas table have field id (this is bank id), name (this is bank name), type (there exist type of bank, order status etc. So, get type = bank)

Users_banks table have field id, user_id, bank_id, status, account_name, account_number, branch

When run, it does not successfully insert into the pivot table (table users_banks).

It looks like my way to insert into the pivot table, not true.

Can you help me?

**Additional**

Table Master_datas is like this :

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not passing `bank_id` in your `addUserBank()` method. you can do it as:

```
public function addUserBank($param)
{
    $param['status'] = 0;
    auth()->user()
          ->banks()
          ->attach($param['bank_id'], array_only($param, ['status', 'account_name', 'account_number', 'branch']);
    return true;
}
```

*Note: You don't need to set `user_id` explicitly here as Laravel will automatically do it for you.*

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships)

Comment: Great. It works. Thanks. You look at my question. I update the user model. This: `public function banks()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(MasterData::class, 'users_banks', 'user_id', 'bank_id')  ->withPivot('status','account_name','account_number','branch')->withTimestamps();
    }` Is it really like that?

Answer (score 1):

Create `UserBank` model:

```
 <?php
    namespace App;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    class UserBank extends model 
    {
        protected $table = 'user_banks';
        protected $fillable = ['user_id','bank_id'];
    }
```

And then populate the table from controller:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $param = $request->only('account_name','account_number','bank_id','branch');
    $result = $this->user_service->addUserBank($param);

    if($result)
    { 
        $pivot=new UserBank();
        $pivot->user_id=auth()->user()->id;
        $pivot->bank_id=$request->bank_id;
        if($pivot->save())
         {
             $status='success';
         }
    }
    else
    {            
            $status = 'failed';
    }

    return redirect('member/profile/setting/account')->with('status',$status);
}
```

Comment: There exist error : `Unknown column 'master_data_id' in 'field list'`. Seems addUserBank function in the service, attach process is still wrong

Comment: I update my question. Master_datas table has an some master table, that table with type bank, order_status and payment_method. Maybe it was that caused the error